# How to label json data from database export for dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I've got a json file which contains a few thousand entries, each of which being data related to a horse race. I aim to train a PyTorch model on this data to predict the winner.

The data is currently all in one file, and I would like to train a model to predict the "winner" field. What is the best way for me to label this data, is it possible to do it with one large json file, or should each entry in the dataset be it's own json file, with the corresponding label in a sister folder to the folder containing all the dataset entries?

I'm not fully set on PyTorch, so I'm open to suggestions from other python libraries/frameworks, if they make this easier. I'm also completely new to PyTorch, so my apologies if this is a silly question.

An example of a dataset entry:

```
race: {
 'race': {'competitors': ['hrs_1',
                          'hrs_2',
                          'hrs_3',
                          'hrs_4',
                          'hrs_5',
                          'hrs_6',
                          'hrs_7',
                          'hrs_8'],
          'country': 'IRE',
          'date': '2023-07-22',
          'distance': '2640',
          'draw': ['5', '7', '4', '2', '8', '6', '1', '3'],
          'going': 'Soft',
          'prize_money': 285000.0,
          'race_index': 7,
          'surface': 'turf',
          'winner': {
                     'horse': 'Savethelastdance',
                     'horse_id': 'hrs_1',
                     'sex': 'F',
                     'trainer': 'A P OBrien',
                     'weight': '9-2',
                     'weight_lbs': '128'}}}
  
},
{'horse': {'0': {'age': '3',
                 'name': 'Be Happy',
                 'nationality': 'IRE',
                 'odds': '26.00',
                 'rating': '98',
                 'sex': 'F',
                 'trainer': 'trn_71802',
                 'weight': '128',
                 'weight_change': 0.0},
```

I want the above to be the data entry, and the label to be `race.winner.horse`

What's the best way for me to structure this?

PS. The plan is for this to be a standard, feed-forward neural network.

Comment: You don't have to make separate files for every entry. A single JSON file should be enough. Just put them inside JSON array where each entry represents a data point.

Comment: Are you aware that the horse racing industry already does exactly this?  When you see the "odds" for a given horse, that's the result of a model prediction.  In virtually every circumstance, the numbers you come up with will equal the odds at race time.

Comment: So what if the horse racing industry already does it? it's a research project. I'm not trying to predict the odds, I'm trying to solve a completely separate research problem. If you don't have anything productive to add except your own opinion on what I should and shouldn't be working on, then I'd kindly ask that you keep the opinion to yourself.